# Getting Error while writing a Large datarame of 60K rows into csv in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

I am trying to build an prediction model. I am trying to do that in 2 parts

1. Preprocesing of the data in python file(.ipynb) and saving this preprocesed 
     data into a csv file

   2. Calling this preprocessed file in the Step 1 Model Prediction (.ipynb) file.

**Preprocessing File**

```
#saving preproccesed dataframe to  csv
train.to_csv('C:/Users/Documents/Tesfile_Preprocessed.csv')

Error 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\sparse\array.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    417             return self._get_val_at(key)
    418         elif isinstance(key, tuple):
--> 419             data_slice = self.values[key]
    420         else:
    421             if isinstance(key, SparseArray):



IndexError: too many indices for array
```

**Prediction Model File**

```
X_test=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Documents/Tesfile_Preprocessed.csv')
predicted_dtree = fit_decision.predict(X_test)
```

How can I Solve This isue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach is to use [to_pickle](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html):

```
train.to_pickle('C:/Users/Documents/Tesfile_Preprocessed.pickle')
```

Too many indices' means you've given too many index values. You've given 2 values as you're expecting data to be a 2D array. Numpy is complaining because data is not 2D (it's either 1D or None).

I recommend you to check the array dimensions before accessing it.

```
self.values.shape
```

or

```
len(self.values)
```

This is NOT related to your Pandas, you are trying to access an not existing index on your array.

Please try to change the `sep` during the export.

```
train.to_csv('C:/Users/Documents/Tesfile_Preprocessed.csv', sep='\t')
```

Comment: ~train.values.shape~ gave (85419, 208)

Comment: @Rahulrajan can you check if all 85K instances has values diff of undefined?

Comment: I didnt  get you

Comment: please run:  `[i for i,j in enumerate(train) if len(j)==0]` and tell me if you find an instance without value...

Comment: @  I ran the above command and it didnt  find any instance. output returned ~[]~

Comment: ok, the default separator in csv is `,` comma; any change to create unwanted columns?

Comment: @Rahulrajan just updated the answer please check it out

Comment: I want all the 208 columns

Comment: still giving error `\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py in _get_handle(path_or_buf, mode, encoding, compression, memory_map, is_text)
    383         elif is_text:
    384             # Python 3 and no explicit encoding
--> 385             f = open(path_or_buf, mode, errors='replace')
    386         else:
    387             # Python 3 and binary mode

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/Documents/Tesfile_Preprocessed.csv'`

Comment: it's a fileNotFoundError... please check this issue here: https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/2656 

thanks for the attention, upvote the answer and mark as correct...

Comment: The `to_csv` method is going to create a directory and write many files to that directory. I suspect that the filename that you have provided is already a file and so Windows is unable to create a directory of the same name.

Comment: i think `to_pickle` is a better option here

Comment: @Rahulrajan yep! just updated the answer as well... please click on the arrow up to upvote my answer

Comment: Off topic , do you how to print columns  which only null values  .Currently I am using this `df1.isnull().any()`.

Comment: you can check using: `df.dropna(axis=1, how='all')` and check if is missing an entire column... or `df1.isnull().all()`

Comment: I want list the columns where `isnull` is true. Currently its printing both true and false

Comment: Please create another question... upvote the answer thanks.